# Test print program works as stand alone, but fails when added to JavaFX app

Tags: javafx, printing

I wrote a test program to print a graphic. I created a Printable object and drew an image to the Graphics object passed to the print() method. The stand alone application works fine. However, once I copy the code to my JavaFX application it fails to print the image. Even if I "print" to a pdf file, it always creates an empty pdf file. I have printed out the measurements of the imageable area and it is the same as in the test program.

```
imagable area (0.0, 0.0)  -  612.0 x 792.0
```

I am at a loss as to why this fails when moved to the JavaFX program.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue via another test program. It had to do with returning NO_SUCH_PAGE. Basically, I had to recreate the page EVERY time the same page index was sent to print and return PAGE_EXISTS. As I was unclear of this I was erroneously telling the program that I was done printing when it called the method for the same page jndex.